# Bluecoat Proxy has a default proxy-service that permits access to all port range in bypass

Tags: bluecoat

I'm going through my company's bluecoat proxy configuration (6.5.5.1) using

> show proxy-services

```
Service Name:  Default
Service Group: Standard
Proxy:         TCP Tunnel
Attributes:    use-dan, and-byte-cache, ...
Source IP        Destination IP     Port Range     Action
<All>            <Transparent>      <All>          Bypass
```

1. I would like to confirm that all port ranges are accessible without Bluecoat Proxy inspection.
2. It seems strange that this is setup this way, how can i confirm that this proxy-service is active? (I'm just starting out on Bluecoat Proxy and the website does not have much information that I can read up on)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Default** service listener matches all TCP traffic ***not*** otherwise intercepted by other service listeners.  It's action is set to `Bypass` to prevent the ProxySG from interfering with the traffic.

Out of the box, you should see other service listeners for specific traffic types (HTTP, SSL, etc.) in which you can configure interception for protocol detection (inspection), etc.

Comment: Okay - action is set to bypass to prevent ProxySG from interfering with other traffic. I had the idea that all traffic should be set to intercept, akin to firewall rules where all are set to drop in rule 1, now i get a better picture.